# Scala: value class X is added to the return type of its methods as X#

Tags: scala, enrich-my-library

I'd like to enrich a 'graph for scala' graph. For this purpose i've created an implicit value class:

```
import scalax.collection.mutable
import scalax.collection.edge.DiEdge

...
    type Graph = mutable.Graph[Int, DiEdge]
    implicit class EnrichGraph(val G: Graph) extends AnyVal {
        def roots = G.nodes.filter(!_.hasPredecessors)
        ...
    }
...
```

The problem lies with the return type of its methods, e.g.:

```
import ....EnrichGraph

val H: Graph = mutable.Graph[Int,DiEdge]()

val roots1 = H.nodes.filter(!_.hasPredecessors)  // type Iterable[H.NodeT]
val roots2 = H.roots        // type Iterable[RichGraph#G.NodeT] !!

val subgraph1 = H.filter(H.having(roots1)) // works!
val subgraph2 = H.filter(H.having(roots2)) // type mismatch!
```

Does the cause lie with fact that 'Graph' has dependent subtypes, e.g. NodeT? Is there a way to make this enrichment work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What usually works is propagating the singleton type as a type parameter to `EnrichGraph`. That means a little bit of extra boilerplate since you have to split the `implicit class` into  a `class` and an `implicit def`.

```
class EnrichGraph[G <: Graph](val G: G) extends AnyVal {
    def roots: Iterable[G#NodeT] = G.nodes.filter(!_.hasPredecessors)
    //...
}
implicit def EnrichGraph(g: Graph): EnrichGraph[g.type] = new EnrichGraph[g.type](g)
```

The gist here being that `G#NodeT =:= H.NodeT` if `G =:= H.type`, or in other words `(H.type)#NodeT =:= H.NodeT`. (`=:=` is the type equality operator)

The reason you got that weird type, is that `roots` has a path type dependent type. And that path contains the value `G`. So then the type of `val roots2` in your program would need to contain *a path to* `G`. But since `G` is bound to an instance of `EnrichGraph` which is not referenced by any variable, the compiler cannot construct such a path. The "best" thing the compiler can do is construct a type with that part of the path left out: `Set[_1.G.NodeT] forSome { val _1: EnrichGraph }`. This is the type I actually got with your code; I assume you're using Intellij which is printing this type differently.

As pointed out by @DmytroMitin a version which might work better for you is:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Set
class EnrichGraph[G <: Graph](val G: G) extends AnyVal {
    def roots: Set[G.NodeT] = G.nodes.filter(!_.hasPredecessors)
    //...
}
implicit def EnrichGraph(g: Graph): EnrichGraph[g.type] = new EnrichGraph[g.type](g)
```

Since the rest of your code actually requires a `Set` instead of an `Iterable`.

The reason why this still works despite reintroducing the path dependent type  is quite tricky. Actually now `roots2` will receive the type `Set[_1.G.NodeT] forSome { val _1: EnrichGraph[H.type] }` which looks pretty complex. But the important part is that this type still contains the knowledge that the `G` in `_1.G.NodeT` has type `H.type` because that information is stored in `val _1: EnrichGraph[H.type]`.

With `Set` you can't use `G#NodeT` to give you the simpler type signatures, because `G.NodeT` is a subtype of `G#NodeT` and `Set` is unfortunately invariant. In our usage those type will actually always be equivalent (as I explained above), but the compiler cannot know that.

Comment: Maybe, it should be `class EnrichGraph[G <: Graph](val G: G) extends AnyVal {
    def roots: scala.collection.mutable.Set[G.NodeT] = G.nodes.filter(!_.hasPredecessors)
  }`

Comment: It should be `G#NodeT`. The reason OP gets those weird types is that `val G` is bound to an instance of `EnrichGraph`, but that instance is not available to use in a path dependent type. You're probably right about `Set` if I guessed correctly about the library that's being used here, but OP says he wants an `Iterable` so there you go. And `Set` extends `Iterable` so it does work. Unfortunately the question is not self-contained, so working with what _is_ provided seems best :)

Comment: With `G#NodeT` the code doesn't compile in Scala 2.12.8 + graph-core 1.12.5 https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/50faeb1f92011df664d168ffc3c26874 The error is ``type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.Set[EnrichGraph.this.G.NodeT]
[error]  required: scala.collection.mutable.Set[G#NodeT]
[error] Note: EnrichGraph.this.G.NodeT <: G#NodeT, but trait Set is invariant in type A.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: G#NodeT`. (SLS 3.2.10)
``

Comment: Which brings us back to `Iterable[G#NodeT]`, I guess. Or use `Set[_ <: G#NodeT]` like the error suggests.

Comment: With `Iterable[G#NodeT]` error is `type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Iterable[App.H.NodeT]
[error]  required: App.H.NodeFilter
[error]     (which expands to)  App.H.NodeT => Boolean
`. With `scala.collection.mutable.Set[_ <: G#NodeT]` the error is `type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.Set[_$1] where type _$1 <: App.H.NodeT
[error]  required: App.H.NodeFilter
[error]     (which expands to)  App.H.NodeT => Boolean
`.

Comment: I checked that `val roots2 = H.roots` actually received type `Iterable[H.NodeT]` as requested in the question. I don't know anything about this library, so I'm also not qualified to assume or guess any more than what is literally stated in the question...